# Can I undo the action of create a folder in xcode?

Tags: xcode, directory, undo

When we use the Xcode, we can use: cmd + z(Edit, undo)  to undo the action of writing some codes.
Sometimes, I create or delete some folders, what could I do if I want to undo this actions ?

Comment: undo only works in the code editor. the "groups" (the folder icons) are managed by the .pbxproj file. if you don't like a group that you made, empty it of its file by moving them elsewhere and delete the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to this as @Mark Edward Murray mentions all you can do is if you create a group by mistake than simply delete it by reference or move it to trash and maybe if you deleted something accidentally in case if you have removed it by reference you can get it by "add files to project" option in file menu the file will be safe in you project folder where you saved the project or if you had moved that file to trash simply take it out of the trash and add it again to your folder that's the best you can do.

Comment: When I clicked the button of vote, I was told that "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score".        As I use the stackoverflow first time , it seems that I have no right to mark the right answer?